# Binding an event to a view's el after rendering the view dynamically

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
<div class="container"> // this is the parent div template (already existing in the DOM prior to instantiating the View
```

HTML template:

```
  <div id="measure-cid1"> // the number is dynamic
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="remove-measure-rep"><i class="icon-minus"</i></div>
    </div>
    …other stuff…
  </div>
  <div id="measure-cid2">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="remove-measure-rep"><i class="icon-minus"</i></div>
    </div>
    …other stuff…
  </div>
  … multiple other 'measure-cid*'s
// remaining portion from the parent div template
</div>
```

BB JS View:

```
define([…], …){ //using require
  return Backbone.View.extend({
    // I can not define the el here, as it is dynamic, so I have to set it in the init
    events : {
      'click .remove-measure-rep' : 'removeRepresentation',
      'click' : 'removeRepresentation'
    },
    initialize: function(options){
      if (options) {
        //passing options.* to this view as this.*
        for (var key in options) {
          this[key] = options[key];
        }
        console.log(this.el); // I get `<div></div>`
        this.el = '#measure-rep-'+this.measureRepModel.cid;
        console.log(this.el); // This returns `#measure-rep-c28`
        this._ensureElement();
        console.log(this.el); //This returns `undefined`
        this._ensureElement($('#measure-rep-'+this.measureRepModel.cid));
        console.log(this.el); //this returns `<div></div>`
        this.setElement($('#measure-rep-'+this.measureRepModel.cid));
        console.log(this.el); // this returns `undefined`
      }

      //Dispatch listeners
      …  
      //Binding  
      this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));

      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      // I attach the template to its parent div 
      var compiledTemplate = _.template( MeasureRepTemplate, measureRepTemplateParamaters );
      // put in the rendered template in the measure-rep-container of the measure
      $(this.repContainerEl).append( compiledTemplate );

    },
    removeRepresentation: function(ev){
      console.log('getting here');
    }
  })
};
```

After reading that the `el` is created even as a temporary holder prior to the init, I can't figure out how to capture the clicking of the class `'.remove-measure-rep'`.  I also verified on the template that the class `remove-measure-rep` was within the template, and not elsewhere, as it seems other SO questions regarding not getting the event captured deal with the View looking for classes or ids only within their own template.  The View should be creating HTML, and adding it to the DOM.

How do I get the View to have access to the click event?, as it isn't registering when I set the el to the different values in the init. I tried each of those individually and it still isn't working.  Does it have to do with setting the template in a div and then trying to bind an element from the template to the VIew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't mess with `this.el`. Just let backbone define your view's element for you
2. In your template, omit the outermost `<div>` tag as that will be the backbone one
3. Inside `render`, just set the ID you want

---

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
      'click .remove-measure-rep' : 'removeRepresentation',
      'click' : 'removeRepresentation'
    },
    initialize: function(options){
      if (options) {
        //passing options.* to this view as this.*
        for (var key in options) {
          this[key] = options[key];
        }
        //don't mess with this.el at all
      }

      //Dispatch listeners
      …  
      //Binding
      //better to use listenTo here
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', _.bind(this.render, this));  
      //I think initialize calling render is an antipattern. Discouraged.
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      //Here you can set your dynamic ID
      this.$el.attr('id', 'measure-cid' + this.model.id);
      // I attach the template to its parent div 
      var compiledTemplate = _.template( MeasureRepTemplate, measureRepTemplateParamaters );
      // put in the rendered template in the measure-rep-container of the measure
      //view's appending themselves to the DOM is also an antipattern in my book, but anyway..
      $(this.repContainerEl).append( compiledTemplate );

    },
    removeRepresentation: function(ev){
      console.log('getting here');
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: You could use `id: function() { return this.model.id }` instead of doing it by hand in `render`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AGTsE/

Comment: @Peter Lyons @PeterLyons You say that `View's appending themselves to the DOM is an antipattern`, so how would you suggest the addition of a view?  By it's parent? Maybe I am just too new to this structure, so any link that explains this in detail would also be appreciated.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: Think of a view as a re-usable component. Like a widget such as a select box or a calendar date picker. Should it be able to work with 1 and only 1 parent document? Should it dictate what it's parent selector is? Views should be appended to the DOM by the router in straight backbone or a parent view or some layout manager/region component if using something like backbone.marionette.